# How can I open a shell in the environment that cron (alternatively launchd) uses to execute commands?

Tags: bash, shell, sudo, cron

I am trying to get launchd (which is macOS's alternative for cron) to run a job for me. It doesn't work, while running the commands on a bash launched with sudo does. I tried redirecting the output to files, but examining them hasn't enlightened me, either. I like to have access to this 'primal' environment launchd uses to execute commands, so that I can experiment directly there and see what is missing.

PS: Here is the script I run in my launchd job (as root):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export HOME=/Users/evar
source /users/evar/.bashrc
/Users/evar/anaconda/bin/python /Base/_Code/Misc/hosts/updateHostsFile.py --auto --replace --backup &> /Users/evar/log/hosts.out2
# tmux new -d -s hosts "/Users/evar/anaconda/bin/python /Base/_Code/Misc/hosts/updateHostsFile.py --auto --replace --backup" # I tried this, but sudo tmux kept saying no sessions while logs kept said "duplicate session hosts".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning of your script you could do something like

```
env > /tmp/myscriptrun_env.$$
```

This will put the inherited environment into a file in `/tmp`.

Now from the command line you can use the command `env -i /bin/sh` to generate a new shell with a fresh environment.  Inside this shell you can `source` the `/tmp` file you created.

You may want to edit it first and add `export` in front of each line to better mimic the launched environment.

Comment: Then I do `sudo bash -c “env < /tmp/my...”`?

Comment: No.  The output is, effectively, a script.  But rather than use it directly you should manually inspect it and see if anything important is missing that your program relies on (normally a PATH, or similar) and then set them at the beginning of your script

Comment: You see, as far as I can see NOTHING is missing. So I want to be in that exact environment and experiment to see what I can uncover.

Comment: Use `env -i /bin/sh` to get a blank environment then `source /tmp/my....` to import the values

Comment: Add this to the answer, I have already marked it as correct. Thanks!